# Installing Laravel through composer generates error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When trying to install Laravel using the terminal command `composer create-project laravel/laravel test_project` I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The process has been signaled with signal "11".
```

I've googled and although one or two others have reported the problem, no one has a solution.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing Laravel through Composer, I ran into this problem because `Symfony` took far too long to install -and thus resulted in a `runtime exception`.

Although not a direct solution to your problem, I will offer an alternative route for installing Laravel -via download. This is, of course, assuming you have `Composer` globally installed on your System:

1. Grab yourself the [latest copy](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip) of Laravel 4 Framework.
2. Extract zip to your project folder (i.e. /var/www/new_project/ folder).
3. Run `composer install` or `php composer.phar install` -this will install Laravel 4 and its dependencies which include `Symfony`.
4. Lastly, make sure your `app/storage` has the proper file permission (i.e. `chmod -R 777 /var/www/new_project/app/storage`)

This will install Laravel 4 freshly on your system. Using this alternate route may prove to be faster than installing directly from composer. For some odd reason, composer and laravel take an extraordinarily long time to install -- and if too long -- could result in a runtime exception.